# How to create measures in Power BI using IF?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with a column named Brand. This column contains ours as well as our competitors' product name. I am trying to calculate the price difference of our product with each of our competitor's products.
What DAX function should I use? Also, `IF()` is not allowing to create measures without any aggregation function.

Comment: Show you sample data with your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try and refer below links posted in power bi community.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/IF-Statement-Power-BI-Desktop/td-p/32306

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/IF-statement-in-dax/td-p/524310

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Multiple-IF-statement-DAX/td-p/982633

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax

And try conditional columns in **transform data** section